# Localize analytics page strings

Tags: feature-request, localization, site-analytics

Could you make those strings on the site analytics page available for localization?

> [image]

Comment: I'm an English-only speaker, but this makes perfect sense to me. I'd also guess if the x axis legend isn't localizable, the y axis legend isn't, either. Arabic numerals may be much more commonly shared between languages than the names of months, but they're still not universal. I also note there is text I can read on that page right above the upper red box. Was it required that the date range be specified in English?